# vb 2010 Error when trying to save to SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have deleted the SQL Server database I was previously using and replaced it with a SQL Server Compact Edition database due to research showing that this type of database will prove better suited to my small desktop application.

Previously, the following code worked fine for my first database, however now that I have changed for a compact database, this produces an error when the binding navigator save button is clicked.

The data is loaded fine from the compact database, but are there any changes I have to make to allow saving to the compact database in this way?

Thank you for your time.

```
  Private Sub CompactTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CompactTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.CompactTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CompactDatabaseDataSet1)
            MsgBox("Update Successful")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Update Failed" & ex.ToString)
        End Try

End Sub
```

The error produced states:

> update failedsystem.data.sqlserverCe.sqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token Line offset = 337, Token in error = (] at linkageanalysisprogram.compactdatabasedataset1tableadapters.tableadaptermanager.updateAll(compactdatabasedataset1 dataset) in C:\TestApp\compactdatabasedataset1.designer.vb:line 2138 at form1.compactbindingnavigatorsaveitem_click(object_sender,eventargs e) in C:\TestApp\Form1.vb:line 4071

Comment: Any time your code “produces an error ” it is pretty important to **show us the error**.

Comment: Apologies I meant to add the error message. I have now added it. Thanks

Comment: If I delete a row of data from my table and then press save, it works fine, it is only when I change a number in the table to a different number and then press save that it will not work